# How Can I remove AuthorizeAreaFolder option from service in integration test

Tags: c#, integration-testing, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1, xunit.net

I have a integration test for my razor web application with custom WebApplicationFactory:

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup>
    : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(
                d => d.ServiceType ==
                    typeof(DbContextOptions<GenericDbContext>));

            services.Remove(descriptor);


            services.AddDbContext<GenericDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseInMemoryDatabase("InMemoryDbForTesting");
            });

            var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            using var scope = sp.CreateScope();

            var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
            var db = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<GenericDbContext>();
            var logger = scopedServices
                .GetRequiredService<ILogger<CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup>>>();

            db.Database.EnsureCreated();

            try
            {
                Utilities.InitializeDbForTests(db);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred seeding the " +
                    "database with test messages. Error: {Message}", ex.Message);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In the TStartup I am passing this startup configure services:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

    //AzureADB2C
    services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
    {
        sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    
    .AddAzureAdB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("Authentication:AzureAdB2C", options))
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        //options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
    });
    //AzureADB2C

    //Simple
    //services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    //    .AddAzureADB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("Authentication:AzureAdB2C", options));


    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false; // = context => true; //When set to true, TempData will not work unless the user opts in.
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified; //If we dont do the hack for chrome/safari, this should be set to 'None'
        options.Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;

        //Hack for Chrome/Safari. May not be needed in future
        options.OnAppendCookie = cookieContext =>
            CheckSameSite(cookieContext.Context, cookieContext.CookieOptions);
        options.OnDeleteCookie = cookieContext =>
           CheckSameSite(cookieContext.Context, cookieContext.CookieOptions);
    });

    services.AddRouting(options => {
        options.LowercaseUrls = true;
        //options.AppendTrailingSlash = false;
        });


 
    //Response Caching
    services.AddResponseCaching();

    //With conditional runtime compilation
    IMvcBuilder builder = services.AddRazorPages()
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            //Sitemap
            options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("xxxxxx", "/xxxxxx", "xxxxxx.xml");
            options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("xxxxxx", "/xxxxxx", "xxxxxx/xxxxxx.xml");
            options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("xxxxxx", "/xxxxxx", "xxxxxx/xxxxxx.xml");
            options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("xxxxxx", "/xxxxxx", "xxxxxx/xxxxxx.xml");
            options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("xxxxxx", "/xxxxxx", "xxxxxx/xxxxxx.xml");
            options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("xxxxxx", "/xxxxxx", "xxxxxx/xxxxxx.xml");
            options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("xxxxxx", "/xxxxxx", "xxxxxx/xxxxxx.xml");



            options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("xxxxxx", "/");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("xxxxxx", "/");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("xxxxxxx", "/", "xxxxx");
            //options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("xxxx", "/");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("xxxxxx", "/");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("xxxxxx", "/");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("xxxxxx", "/");
            //options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("xxxxx", "/");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("xxxx", "/xxxxx");


            //password reset
            options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToAreaPage("xxxxx", "/xxxxx");
            options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToAreaPage("xxxxx", "/xxxx");

            //Checkout and 3DS pages
            options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToAreaPage("xxxxx", "/xxxxx");


        });

    services.AddMemoryCache();

    //CACHE for tokens
    // Adds a default in-memory implementation of IDistributedCache.
    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
    //services.AddSession();

    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;// SameSiteMode.None;
        //options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
    });


    services.AddDbContext<IGenericDbContext, GenericDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("GenericDbConnection")));
}
```

Like I am removing dbContextOption in the custom WebApplicationFactory, I want to remove AuthorizeAreaFolder or to override "services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions()" to allow integration test to get or post a page without faking authorization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`AddRazorPagesOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvcrazorpagesmvcbuilderextensions.addrazorpagesoptions?view=aspnetcore-3.1) essentially just configures the [`RazorPagesOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.razorpagesoptions?view=aspnetcore-3.1) on the service collection, so it is equivalent to the following:

```cs
services.Configure<RazorPagesOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("xxxxxx", "/");
    // …
});
```

That also means that in order to change the conventions, you can reconfigure the `RazorPagesOptions` and modify the conventions collection directly. Unfortunately, the [`IPageConvention`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.applicationmodels.ipageconvention?view=aspnetcore-3.1) types are private, so you cannot look for the entries that are added by [`AuthorizeAreaFolder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.pageconventioncollectionextensions.authorizeareafolder?view=aspnetcore-3.1) directly and remove them with the [`RemoveType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.applicationmodels.pageconventioncollection.removetype?view=aspnetcore-3.1) method. However, you could [clear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1.clear) the whole collection to remove all conventions completely:

```cs
services.Configure<RazorPagesOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.Clear();
});
```